# Add rows to csv file with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, csv

I'm trying to add new rows of data to my existing csv file. I have allready managed to get the existing rows in the csv file using:

```
             $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "gigs.csv",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {processData(data);}
             });
```

So now I'm trying this to add a new row: ( the `var gig` is just test data)

```
<script>
var gig='10;Magnus;THisMagnus;UKA;2014-12-12;18.00';

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'gigs.csv',
                contentType: "text/csv",
                data: gig,
                success: function(data) {alert("Success")}
            });
</script>
```

The csv file is `;` separated, I know that for a fact. When I run the code I get the "success" alert, but there is no new row in my csv file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That... just won't work. You'll need to have a server-side script/handler that accepts the new data and updates the file.

Comment: Imagine the security holes that would exist if this DID work. You need a script running on the server to write to the file, at the very least. It should also authenticate the request and validate the input. And what about duplicate requests/concurrent users? You might want to consider using a database backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just post data and have it add to the .csv file without some sort of handling on the server side, otherwise anyone could vomit data onto any server. It would be a security nightmare.

Your best bet is probably to set up server-side script handling or an API to deal with your ajax requests. C# MVC Web API is one easy way, you can keep your JavaScript basically intact and send your post to a C# backend that will then be able to parse the input and add it to your .csv. There are lots of other frameworks as well, that's just the one I'm most familiar with.